# How Do I Update a Table From Another Table Only If the Result Count is 1?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update, having

I have a table of 2 tables in a one to many relationship.  I want to run an update script that will update the table with the FK of the related table only if there is one result (because if there is multiple then we need to decide which one to use, in another method)

Here is what I have so far:

```
UPDATE import_hourly_event_reports i
   SET i.banner_id = b.banner_id
  FROM banner b
  JOIN plan p ON b.plan_id = p.id
 WHERE b.campain_id = i.campaign_id
   AND b.size_id = i.size_id
   AND p.site_id = i.site_id
HAVING COUNT(b.banner_id) = 1
```

As you can see, the `HAVING` clause doesn't quite work as I'd expect it.  I only want to update the row in the import table with the id of the banner from the banner table if the count is equal to 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
UPDATE import_hourly_event_reports i
   SET i.banner_id = b.banner_id
  FROM banner b
  JOIN plan p ON b.plan_id = p.id
 WHERE b.campain_id = i.campaign_id
   AND b.size_id = i.size_id
   AND p.site_id = i.site_id
   AND (SELECT COUNT(b1.banner_id)
          FROM banner b1
          JOIN plans p1 ON b1.plan_id = p1.id
         WHERE b1.campain_id = i.campaign_id
           AND b1.size_id = i.size_id
           AND p1.site_id = i.site_id) = 1
```

Comment: in this case, it will always yield 1 because banner_id is unique.

Comment: Well they were going off of your count(b1.banner_id) I think. Just adapt to select count from plan table instead.

Comment: ill accept this, as it was the basis for my solution.  I will also edit it to make it accurate to my scenario.